# How do I make a button within an HTML table, to update info in my database

Tags: php, html, button, mysqli

I am totally new to coding. That being said I hope you can help me with this issue I am having.
I use PHP and Mysqli to populate information within a html table. I have added a button in one of the columns. I want to click the button and update the information on that row of the table, in the database.
The users earn a commission, so by clicking the button, I want to move the amount in the "pay" column to the "paid" column and update the database.

When I click the button, I get the "success" message that says "Payment Processed Successfully", but nothing changes in the database!
Thanks ahead of time for any help you can provide.
Here's my code:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div class="form">

 <h2>View Records</h2>

 <table  width='100%'> 
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th><strong>user ID</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Fist Name</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
 <th><strong>pay commission</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Paid</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Pay Commission</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php
     $count=1;
     include "db.php";
     $sql = "SELECT  * FROM users  ";
     $result = $conn-> query($sql);
       if($result -> num_rows > 0){
     while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) { ?>

   <td align="center"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?></td>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?></td>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row["pay"]; ?></td>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row["paid"]; ?></td>
   <td align="center">
   <div class="input-group">
   <form class="reset-form" action="members.php" method="post" >
   <div class="input-group">
   <button type="submit" class="button_1" name="pay-commission">Pay Commission</button></div></form>

   </td>
   <td align="center">
   <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Delete</a>
   </td>
   </tr>
     <?php
  }

        // process commission*******
        if(isset($_POST["pay-commission"])){

       $id=$row['id'];
       $pay=$row['pay'];
       $paid=$row['last_paid']; 

      //date and time of transaction
          $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    require('db.php');
    $ins_query="update users  last_paid='$pay' trm_date='$trn_date'  where id= '$id'";

            mysqli_query($conn,$ins_query);

         if($ins_query){
        echo "<p class= 'success'> Payment Processed Successfully <p>"; 
          }else{
       echo"<p class= 'error'>something went wrong!!</p>";
          }
            }
           }

      ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$ins_query="update users SET  last_paid='$pay' trm_date='$trn_date'  where id= '$id'";` you forgot to add `SET` in your query

Comment: also you are not sending any data with form, here you may add some hidden input box, and set there value from your database.

Comment: `<form class="reset-form" action="members.php" method="post" >
   <div class="input-group">
   <button type="submit" class="button_1" name="pay-commission">Pay Commission</button></div></form>`
**your form is empty**

Comment: `$id=$row['id'];
       $pay=$row['pay'];
       $paid=$row['last_paid']; ` makes no sense inside `if(isset($_POST["pay-commission"]`. 1) You don't actually know which row was clicked based on that, and you certainly don't want to update all of them. 2) you _are_ updating the rows, but only with exactly the same data which was already there. As MUFAzmi hints, you need a) some input fields in your table rows instead of just static data, and b) to capture the values of those input fields via $_POST when you submit.

Comment: The posted code contains too many syntax errors. There are more than posted in comments.

Comment: I was able to resolve the main issue on my own, fisrt of all I need to move the closing bracket, to the bottom of the file, so that all the code was included in the function, so it can excute at database lever

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was able to catch a few issues, and correct them. I can now update the database, with what I have, but it actually updates all users with one click, which I'm thinking is not too bad. You process commissions once a month with one click, but for the sake of having the option one row at a time, I could use some help with that.

Answer (score -1):

got it working except it updates all users with one click on any button in the "pay commission" column. may not be a bad thing to process all commissions with one click.
Maybe I move the button below the table, to update all users with one click. all of this code is on a page called members.php

```
 <html>
 <head></head> <header></header>

  <body>
  //table structure

<div class="form">
<h2>View Records</h2>

<table  width='100%'> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th><strong>user ID</strong></th>
<th><strong>Fist Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>pay commission</strong></th>
<th><strong>Paid</strong></th>
<th><strong>Pay Commission</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

     //populate table with user data

<?php
$count=1;
    include "db.php";
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM users  ";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
if($result -> num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) { ?>

    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["pay"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["last_paid"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
    <div class="input-group">
    <form  action="members.php" method="post" >
    <div class="input-group">
    <button type="submit" class="button_1" name="pay-commission">Pay           commission</button></div></form>

    </td>
    <td align="center">
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Delete</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php


// process commission*******
    if(isset($_POST["pay-commission"])){

$id=$row['id'];
$pay=$row['pay'];
$paid=$row['last_paid'];

    //set the date and time of transaction

$trn_date = date('Y-m-d');




$conn->query("UPDATE users SET  last_paid='$pay'  WHERE id= '$id'");
$conn->query("UPDATE users SET  pay=0.00 WHERE id= '$id'");
$conn->query("UPDATE users SET  trn_date='$trn_date' WHERE id= '$id'");


if($conn){
    //refresh the page to see changes
header ('Location: members.php');
echo '<p class="success"> A Payment of $$pay Processed Successfully for member ID     $id</p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p class="error">Something went wrong! </p>';
    }


   }
  }
 }  

$conn->close();
  ?>    

 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>




 </body>
 </html>
```